# Issue with redirecting to a Jquery Tab after an ajax post RSS

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page Import.cshtml that has 2 jquery tabs like:

```
@model Models.BaseDataModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var val = Json.Encode(Model);
}

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
            window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash;
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div class="row-fluid">
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#import-container"><i class="icon-upload icon-large"></i> IMPORT</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#sanitize-container"><i class="icon-list icon-large"></i> SANITIZE</a>
            <span class="badge badge-important">0</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="import-container">
        @Html.Partial("_ImportData", Model)
    </div>
    <div id="sanitize-container">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then in my _ImportData partial view I have a function that posts to my controller on a button click using jquery, like:

```
$('#btn-submit').click(function () {
        var check = @Html.Raw(val)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ProcessAndSaveData", "ImportBaseData")',
              data: JSON.stringify(check),
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              async: true,
              beforeSend: function () {
                  $('#spinner').show();
              },
              success: function (data) {
                  $('#spinner').hide();
                  alert(data.url);
                  if (data.url) {
                      window.location.href = data.url;
                  }
              },
              failure: function () {
              }
          });
    });
```

And then finally in my controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessAndSaveData(BaseDataModel model)
    {
        // Some code
        return Json( new { url = Url.Action("Import", "ImportBaseData", new { area = "BaseData" }) + "#sanitize-container"});
    }
```

But this does not redirect to the Sanitize tab i have in my Import.cshtml view, what am i missing or doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: url: '@Url.Action("ProcessAndSaveData", "ImportBaseData")',?? in ajax can it resolve the url?

Comment: Yeah, it resolves the URL all right, that's why I added that alert in my success method, to double check. So, it gives me the url correct, but does not navigate to the JQuery Tab for some reason. If I refresh the page, it then takes me to the JQuery tab, I passed in the URL. Any ideas?

Comment: window.location.href = data.url;  what does it intended to do ?

Comment: So, in my success function I return a JSON object called url that is set from my controller. If this url is present, window.location.href redirects to the url. Nothing fancy

Comment: may be you should try using  window.location.hash ?? passing #sanitize-container only

Comment: nopes, have tried that, doesn't seem to work